# Limit: $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to\infty}{\frac{e^x-3}{e^x+1}}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Is it correct to write $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to\infty}{\frac{e^x-3}{e^x+1}}=\lim _{x\to\infty}{\frac{e^x}{e^x}}=1$? Can I simply discard $-3$ and $+1$?

Comment: Yes you can. You can also use l'hopital's rule to see to prove it.

Comment: That argument is not good. You should be able to find a simple transformation to show that the -3 and +1 will be negligible in the limit.

Comment: The equality is true, but need to be justified (by l'Hopital for example)... as written it's a bit sloppy...

Comment: In a sense, you can discard the constant terms, but I'd avoid thinking about it like that since it would fail in other similar situations, e.g. $\displaystyle \lim \frac{x^{-1}-3}{x^{-1}+1} \color{red}{\neq} \lim \frac{x^{-1}}{x^{-1}}$, and you need to understand *why* it works here (i.e. the terms' *orders*). Instead, use the rules you're taught for solving limits (which provide the justification for discarding the constant).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but you can multiply numerator and denominator by $e^{-x}$ :

$$\frac{e^x-3}{e^x+1}=\frac{1-3\, e^{-x}}{1+ e^{-x}}\to \frac{1+0}{1+0}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

You can either compute it using the limit rule or you can use Squeeze theorem to prove it.

$$1-\frac{4}{e^x}\le 1-\frac{4}{e^x+1}=\frac{e^x-3}{e^x+1}\le 1$$

Answer (score 1):

This is true

$$\lim _{x\to\infty}{\frac{e^x-3}{e^x+1}}=\lim _{x\to\infty}{\frac{e^x}{e^x}}=1$$

but this is not a correct way to proceed.

Usually, and more in general, we proceed factoring out the dominating term as follows

$$\frac{e^x-3}{e^x+1}=\frac{e^x}{e^x}\cdot \frac{1-\frac{3}{e^x}}{1+\frac{1}{e^x}}\to 1\cdot \frac{1-0}{1+0}=1$$

similarly to the example already given.

In this case, as a simple alternative, we can also proceed as follows

$$\frac{e^x-3}{e^x+1}=\frac{e^x+1-4}{e^x+1}=\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+1}-\frac{4}{e^x+1}=1-\frac{4}{e^x+1}\to 1-0=1$$

Answer (score 1):

I think first you would want to prove that you can discard the -3 in the numerator, which you can do simply splitting the fraction in two, e^x/(1+e^x)-3/(1+e^x). Clearly the minus part goes to 0 as x goes to infinite and you're left with e^x/(1+e^x). That goes to 1, but you can prove it by multiplying top and bottom by e^-x to get
1/(e^(-x)+1)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).